# How to add duplicate label using directlabels package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(directlabels)
dat <- structure(list(time.course = c("CONTROL", "DAY03", "DAY06", "DAY09", 
"DAY12", "DAY15", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "DAY06", "DAY09", "DAY12", 
"DAY15", "CONTROL", "DAY03", "DAY06", "DAY09", "DAY12", "DAY15", 
"CONTROL", "DAY03", "DAY06", "DAY09", "DAY12", "DAY15"), log_delta = c(0, 
0.620163956872191, 0.97251217133899, 0.788819459139427, 0.412543422847407, 
0.401621905837411, 0, -0.168711062429047, -0.973481367557294, 
-1.46433243027353, -1.34771037206345, -1.77709667157235, 0, -0.187344700204557, 
-0.254280909246003, -0.335330756378048, -0.655121382977672, -1.1733031812697, 
0, -0.0160729795971869, -0.628563089917479, -1.43060414378064, 
-1.466051599194, -2.57510172892555), `UMAP cluster` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"
), class = "factor"), cell_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Macrophage", "Enteroendocrine", 
"Endothelial", "Lymphatic", "Fibroblast", "T cell", "Myofibroblast", 
"Absorbtice & secrectory cell", "Plasmacytoid DC", "Neutrophil", 
"Plasma cell", "Cajal intestinal cell", "Glial cell", "Germinal center B cell"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


dat
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
   time.course log_delta `UMAP cluster` cell_name    
   <chr>           <dbl> <fct>          <fct>        
 1 CONTROL        0      1              Macrophage   
 2 DAY03          0.620  1              Macrophage   
 3 DAY06          0.973  1              Macrophage   
 4 DAY09          0.789  1              Macrophage   
 5 DAY12          0.413  1              Macrophage   
 6 DAY15          0.402  1              Macrophage   
 7 CONTROL        0      5              Fibroblast   
 8 DAY03         -0.169  5              Fibroblast   
 9 DAY06         -0.973  5              Fibroblast   
10 DAY09         -1.46   5              Fibroblast   
11 DAY12         -1.35   5              Fibroblast   
12 DAY15         -1.78   5              Fibroblast   
13 CONTROL        0      7              Myofibroblast
14 DAY03         -0.187  7              Myofibroblast
15 DAY06         -0.254  7              Myofibroblast
16 DAY09         -0.335  7              Myofibroblast
17 DAY12         -0.655  7              Myofibroblast
18 DAY15         -1.17   7              Myofibroblast
19 CONTROL        0      13             Myofibroblast
20 DAY03         -0.0161 13             Myofibroblast
21 DAY06         -0.629  13             Myofibroblast
22 DAY09         -1.43   13             Myofibroblast
23 DAY12         -1.47   13             Myofibroblast
24 DAY15         -2.58   13             Myofibroblast
```

Notice that "Myofibroblast" occurs twice as `UMAP cluster` 7 and 13.

I tried to plot that using this code with [directlabels package](https://github.com/tdhock/directlabels):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time.course, y = log_delta, 
                                                      color = cell_name)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = `UMAP cluster`)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 2.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("log(proportion / control proportion)") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = cell_name), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.3), "last.bumpup", cex = 0.8))
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Notice that `Myofibroblast` doesn't occur at the end of the two lines (blue).
What I want to do is

1. to color Myofibroblast with two colors
2. each of Myofibroblast lines also tagged with labels.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you cannot do it with directlabels. I can write a quick function to do that. Regarding point 2., What do you want to label the lines with? Celltype or cluster

Comment: You can change cell_name in your original data frame such that one cluster is associated with "Myofibroblast" and the other "Myofibroblast " (with space at the back). That avoids the issue with duplicated labels, & your original code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it with geom_dl because it inherits the aes and directly takes the column variable to be the label. I can think of two solutions, first, is to create a new variable by fusing the cluster id with cell type:

```
# the column name is giving some problems
colnames(dat)[3] = "UMAPcluster"

dat <- dat %>% mutate(new=paste(cell_name,UMAPcluster))
dat$new <- factor(dat$new,levels=unique(dat$new))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = time.course, y = log_delta,,group=new,col = new)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 2.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("log(proportion / control proportion)") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = new), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.3), "last.bumpup", cex = 0.8))
```

[image]

Or you create a new data frame and annotate with geom_text (or geom_label if you like boxes). Preferably you keep the legend for the cluster so that it is clear what the colors mean.

```
LAB = dat %>% group_by(UMAPcluster) %>% top_n(1,wt=time.course)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = time.course, y = log_delta,color = UMAPcluster)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = UMAPcluster)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 2.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("log(proportion / control proportion)") + 
  geom_label(data=LAB,aes(label=cell_name),show.legend=FALSE,nudge_x=0.7)
```

[image]